# When reading a file with 3 characters per line, sizeof(char) doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, char, sizeof

I'm reading a file called `data.txt` with looks like the following:

```
b    5
b    2
b    9
```

Each line has 3 characters: the space between being a **tab**.

I have the following code to read one line at a time.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    FILE * filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char singleLine[3*sizeof(char)];

    while(!feof(filePointer)){
        fgets(singleLine, 3*sizeof(char), filePointer);
        //printCharArray(singleLine); 
        puts(singleLine);
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}
```

singleLine is basically the buffer that the text of each line is put into. I originally made it like `char singleLine[20]`, an arbitrary big enough number, but I want it to be exact so I did `char singleLine(3*sizeof(char))`. My logic was each line has 3 characters, so this should work.

Sadly it did not, when running it, it printed out like the following:

```
b 

5

b 

2

b 

9
```

When I do the careless way, `char singleLine[20]`, it works correctly as shown below. But I want to do it the correct way. What is wrong?

```
b    5
b    2
b    9
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so there's rarely any reason to write it explicitly.

Comment: The *correct way* is not to be so stingy with your buffer size. If you think your max size is `3`, then a `32` char buffer should suffice. And see [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: `fgets()` wants to read a _line_ of text like `b`, `tab`, `5`, `line feed` - that is 4 characters.  After reading a _line_, `fgets()` appends a _null character_.  So `singleLine[]` should be at least `singleLine[5]`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your array has room only for two characters and the null terminator.
2. Your lines have four characters (including a newline).